# How to check if model parameter with is >= with repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, variables, repository-pattern

In this method, I want to check that the `var Total` don't exceed the TotalMonths variable.

The problem is, that the `var Total` is always received with a value of zero, and I don't understad why. Here the method:

```
/********EDIT MONTH DETAILS POST*********/
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult EditMonthDetail(BudgetViewModel budget)
    {

        //var Total = budget.FBudget.UnitPrice * budget.FBudget.Quantity;
        //budget.FBudget.TotalAmount = budget.FBudget.UnitPrice * budget.FBudget.Quantity;
        //var Total = _unitOfWork.Budget.Get(budget.FBudget.TotalAmount);
        var Total = BudgetVM.FBudget.TotalAmount;

        /*Always retrieved with 0*/
        if (Total >= budget.FBudget.TotalMonths)
        {
            _unitOfWork.Budget.EditMonthDetails(BudgetVM.FBudget);
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("FailedTotal");

}
```

Here is how the TotalAmount is implemented in the model:

```
    public float TotalAmount
    {
        get
        {
            return UnitPrice * Quantity;
        }
        
    }
```

Here is the View with a form of type Post:

```
 @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        var title = "title";
    }
    
    <form method="post" asp-action="EditMonthDetail">
    
        <div class="row px-2 mx-2">
    
            <div class="col-12">
                @if (Model.FBudget.BudgetId != 0)
                {
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="FBudget.BudgetId" />
                    title = "Edit Month details";
                }
                <br />
                <h2 class="text-primary">@title</h2>
            </div>
    
            <br />
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="FBudget.Jan"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="FBudget.Jan" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FBudget.Jan" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
    
            <br />
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="FBudget.Feb"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="FBudget.Feb" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FBudget.Feb" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
    
            <br />
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="FBudget.Mar"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="FBudget.Mar" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FBudget.Mar" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
    
            <br />
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="FBudget.Apr"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="FBudget.Apr" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FBudget.Apr" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
    
            <br />
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="FBudget.May"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="FBudget.May" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FBudget.May" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
    
            <br />
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="FBudget.Jun"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="FBudget.Jun" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FBudget.Jun" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
    
            <br />
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="FBudget.Jul"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="FBudget.Jul" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FBudget.Jul" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
    
            <br />
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="FBudget.Ago"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="FBudget.Ago" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FBudget.Ago" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
    
            <br />
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="FBudget.Sept"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="FBudget.Sept" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FBudget.Sept" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
    
            <br />
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="FBudget.Oct"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="FBudget.Oct"class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FBudget.Oct" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
    
            <br />
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="FBudget.Nov"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="FBudget.Nov"class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FBudget.Nov" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
    
            <br />
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="FBudget.Dec"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="FBudget.Dec"class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="FBudget.Dec" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
    
            <br />
    
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-8 offset-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Update</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

I also tried to create a `GetTotalAmount()` method in the repository but it doesn't seems to work.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Here is the model:

```
namespace SalesBudget.Models
{
public class FBudget
{
    
    [Key]
    public int BudgetId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Year is required.")]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "FoC is required.")]
    public string FreeOfCharge { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Currency is required.")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unit price is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Unit Price")]
    public float UnitPrice { get; set; }


    public int Jan { get; set; }
    public int Feb { get; set; }
    public int Mar { get; set; }
    public int Apr { get; set; }
    public int May { get; set; }
    public int Jun { get; set; }
    public int Jul { get; set; }
    public int Ago { get; set; }
    public int Sept { get; set;}
    public int Oct { get; set; }
    public int Nov { get; set; }
    public int Dec { get; set; }

    public int TotalMonths 
    {
        get
        {
            return Jan + Feb + Mar + Apr + May
                + Jun + Jul + Ago + Sept + Oct + Nov + Dec;
        }

    }


    [Display(Name = "Month Nr")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Month Nr is required.")]
    [Range(1, 12, ErrorMessage = "The value must be between 1 and 12!")]
    public string MonthNr { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Unit of Measure")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unit of Measure is required.")]
    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity in untis is required.")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public float TotalAmount
    {
        get
        {
            return UnitPrice * Quantity;
        }
    }

    public string LastUser 
    {
        //automatically set the last user that used the app
        get; set;
    }

    public int ProgramId 
    {
        //automatically set the last sw that used the app
        get; set; 
    }

    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;


    //FKs
    //Access to ItemMaster
    [Display(Name = "Item")]
    public int ItemMasterId { get; set; }
    public ItemMaster ItemMaster { get; set; }

    //Access to Company
    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    //Access to LedgerType
    [Display(Name = "Scenario")]
    public int LedgerTypeId { get; set; }
    public LedgerType LedgerType { get; set; }

    //Access to Customer
    [Display(Name = "Customer")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }


}
}
```

And here is the ViewModel:

```
namespace SalesBudget.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class BudgetViewModel
    {
        public FBudget FBudget { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<FBudget> RecordsList { get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemNumberList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemDescriptionList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PharmaFormList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductGroupList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompanyList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LedgerTypeList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LedgerScenarioList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CustomerList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LicensingAreaList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> YearsList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CurrencyList { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: FYI it doesn't need a `set` if it's just a calculated value.  And have you checked the values of `UnitPrice` and `Quanity` and is one of them 0?

Comment: I can' t see  you model and  I can't see anything about amount in the view too.

Comment: @Serge the amount is not in this view, because I don't need it here. But I need to store this value in order to compare it with TotalAmount when the post request is done

Comment: @juharr Yes, I know, I was trying to do some things. UnitPrice and Quantity are not 0. With the debugger I can see that this variable stores a value.

Comment: @chdev why are you using BudgetVM instead of budget in you controller? that could be your issue

Comment: @chdev thanks, but you still need a price and a quantity

Comment: @Serge the value exists. When I retrieve the value in the View with `@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.FBudget.TotalAmount)` it shows up (with the get request, but not with the post)

Comment: @MorenajeRD are you dominican? :) I tried to do `var Total = budget.FBudget.TotalAmount;` but results always zero

Comment: @chdev yes, i'm dominican, I don't see Quantity in your view.

Comment: @MorenajeRD is not there because i don't need it. But if I add this code to the view:
`Quantity = @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.FBudget.Quantity)
UnitPrice = @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.FBudget.UnitPrice)
Total amount to be matched = @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.FBudget.TotalAmount)` I can see the UnitPrice, the Quantity and the TotalAmount.

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED**

I forgot to add hidden input fields in the view in order to retrieve the values that I needed:

```
<div class="col-12">
        @if (Model.FBudget.BudgetId != 0)
        {
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="FBudget.BudgetId" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="FBudget.Quantity" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="FBudget.UnitPrice" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="FBudget.TotalAmount" />
            title = "Edit Month details";
        }
        <br />
 </div>
```

So now when the form is submitted so are the values captured with hidden fields.